# How can I restore the state of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I have an array of objects `NamedFoos` in my `ViewModel` that represents the available choices for a combobox control.

The problem is that when I serialize the bound variable and then deserialize it again in a later run of the application, **the combobox does not show the value of the object it is bound to**.

The combobox is empty upon startup.

[image: empty combobox]

The source of the problem appears to be that the newly created item is not recognized as an element of the collection.

I wrote a little test app and can reproduce the problem by simply assigning a value to the underlying field of the bound variable (see code below).

If I change the assignment from

```
_selectedFoo = new Bar(2);
```

to

```
_selectedFoo = NamedFoos[1];
```

it works as expected.

I'm aware that de-/serializing just the index of the selection would solve the problem, however serializing the entire object is a requirement.

**How can I let the combobox display the restored value** even if it's not part of the `ItemsSource` collection?

---

## xaml

```
<Window x:Class="test_app.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test_app"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NamedFoos}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFoo}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="ComboBoxDisplayName"/>
</StackPanel>
```

## ViewModel

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace test_app
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        private Foo _selectedFoo;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            _selectedFoo = new Bar(2);
        }


        public Foo[] NamedFoos { get; } =
        {
            new Foo(1),
            new Bar(2)
        };

        public Foo SelectedFoo
        {
            get => _selectedFoo;
            set => _selectedFoo = value;
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class Foo
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int Num { get; set; }

            public Foo(int num)
            {
                Num = num;
            }
            
            public virtual string ComboBoxDisplayName => "foo";
        }

        class Bar : Foo
        {
            public Bar(int num) : base(num)
            {
            }

            public override string ComboBoxDisplayName => "bar";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "the newly created item is not recognized as an element of the collection" is exactly the problem, i.e. `_selectedFoo` and `NamedFoos[1]` are different objects. You can get around it either by overriding the Equals method of the item class, or by using SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath instead of SelectedItem. Or just set `_selectedFoo = NamedFoos[1]`.

Comment: @Clemens providing implementation for Equals did the trick. Would you please post that as an answer?

Comment: Please note that if you provide a custom `Equals` implementation, you have to provide a custom implementation for `GetHashCode`.